# How to get around small cursor keys?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am going to buy a new laptop. But I use the <kbd>Pg Up</kbd>, <kbd>Pg Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys very frequently and there are two major problems for me:

1. Nearly no model contains <kbd>Pg Up</kbd>, <kbd>Pg Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys. Instead, they are usually merged into the cursor keys to be used with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key or with another key combination.
2. Cursor keys for most models are crammed into one small space.

In short, they look like as the following:

[image: Asus Keyboard]

Now, assuming I can remap the combo key to a comfortable place to use the <kbd>Pg Up</kbd>, <kbd>Pg Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys, 1st problem is not a major one. But the 2nd problem is a major one for me because I will be using the cursor keys all the time. Now, even more than before since I have to use the cursor keys to use <kbd>Pg Up</kbd>, <kbd>Pg Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys as well.

My question is, how can I solve this problem? Do you use keyboards without <kbd>Pg Up</kbd>, <kbd>Pg Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys and/or with crammed small cursor keys? If you do, how comfortable are you using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm even more [limited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbOnO.jpg) than you. So I opt to do the following bindings:

- <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> becomes <kbd>Arrow Key Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Pg Down</kbd> becomes <kbd>Arrow Key Down</kbd>
- <kbd>Home</kbd> becomes <kbd>Arrow Key Left</kbd>
- <kbd>End</kbd> becomes <kbd>Arrow Key Right</kbd>

Here's how you can do this:

1. Download and Install [**AutoHotKey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/)
2. > 2.1. Right-Click on your desktop.
   >
   > 2.2. Find "New" in the menu.
   >
   > 2.3. Click "AutoHotkey Script" inside the "New" menu.
   >
   > 2.4. Give the script a new name. Note: It must end with a .ahk extension. Ex. 
   >   MyScript.ahk
   >
   > 2.5. Find the newly created file on your desktop and Right-Click it.
   >
   > 2.6. Click "Edit Script".
3. Insert the **following Script** (Currently working on Windows 10)

   > `Left::send {Home}`
   >
   > `Right::send {End}`
   >
   > `Up::send {PgUp}`
   >
   > `Down::send {PgDn}`
4. Save the file and **run the script**! All done.

   - Remember you can always change "Left Right Up Down" to **whichever keys you want**. See [AHK documentation](http://ahkscript.org/docs/KeyList.htm).
5. **(Optional)** Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd> and type `shell:startup` and place a shortcut of your authotkey script in there and then it will start with Windows

Comment: Although this functionality is built in my computer by using a combo key, remapping is sound too. However, my main concern is the crammed up, small cursor keys. I see your laptop's cursor keys are like that as well. So, do you have trouble using them? Do the small keys cause frustration too much? Or do you get used to them after a while?

Comment: You get used to it. Actually getting used to typing on it comes almost instantly, what is hard is _switching between_ a cramped keyboard and a normal keyboard. That's what takes time getting used to.

Comment: By the way, AFAIK macs' cursor keys can act as pg up, pg down, home and end by using a combo key as well.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I didn't even think to try that simply because I was on Windows. Well we both learned something I guess.

Comment: Haha yes it seems so:)